# Email validation for specific domain name with form action changer

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="email@school.com" required>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>

 <script>
    function IsValidEmail(email)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").submit(function() {
        var allowedDomains = [ 'school1.com', 'school2.com', 'school3.com' ];
        if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
             //acceptable
        }else{
             //not acceptable
        }


    document.getElementById('email').onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById('FORM_ID').action = '/'+this.value;
}
</script>
```

can u help me please
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. What **exactly** are you trying to do? In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it tells us **exactly** what kind of problem you are having. Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)

Comment: I'd guess you could use `pattern` on the input.

Comment: hi and thank you , i need a script form that change action for specific email entred if email end with school1.com then form actoion change t www.school1.com else email end with school2.com form go to school2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this code,

```
<form name="form" id="form_action" method="post" action="">
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="email@school.com" required>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" required>
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="check_email()">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

and this is your javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check_email(){
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if(email == ''){
  alert('Enter email');
  return false;
}
if(email.indexOf('school1.com') !== -1)
{
  document.getElementById("form_action").action ="school1.com";
  document.getElementById('form_action').submit();

} else {
  document.getElementById("form_action").action ="school2.com";
  document.getElementById('form_action').submit();
}
}

</script>
```

you want to answer using javascript so this is javascipt answer

Comment: it's work finaly ^^ i was lookig for this script for a month thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have no form ID, so your `document.getElementByID` has nothing to target. Let's first give it an id `emailform`:

```
<form id="emailform" name="form" method="post" action="">
```

Then you need to run the validity check on change:

```
document.getElementById('email').onchange = function() {
  var allowedDomains = ['school1.com', 'school2.com', 'school3.com'];
  if ($.inArray(this.value, allowedDomains) !== -1) {
    //acceptable
  }
}
```

Then you can simply update the form with jQuery, setting the `action` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('email').onchange = function() {
  var allowedDomains = ['school1.com', 'school2.com', 'school3.com'];
  if ($.inArray(this.value, allowedDomains) !== -1) {
    var action = '/'+this.value;
    $("#emailform").attr("action", action);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)